# #define real function name to __noop in Visual C++ 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2008, c-preprocessor, compiler-flags

I can do this in Visual C++ 2008 with Release (NDEBUG) setting:

**debug.h**

```
#ifdef _DEBUG

void debug_printf(const char* format, ...);

#else

#define debug_printf(format, v)     __noop

#endif
```

**debug.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"  //#include "debug.h" is inside it

void debug_printf(const char* format, ...) {
    //so much work here
}
```

but not anymore in Visual C++ 2013, I will get compile error in debug.cpp file. It seems I have to change the defining strategy in debug.h. But I wonder is there compiler setting to reenable again the old way?

Comment: _What_ compile error? Why do people think not posting it is going to be useful?!

Comment: The error message is a lot: missing ';' before {, unexpected type bla2... like that, it's because the `debug_printf` text in debug.cpp is replaced with `__noop`, so it become: `void __noop(const char* format, ...) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a macro in the first case too, and let it call the actual function (which is named something different from the macro).

And in the second case, just have an empty macro body.

Use [variadic macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415.aspx).

---

Something like

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
# define debug_printf(fmt, ...) real_debug_printf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
# define debug_printf(fmt, ...)
#endif
```

When `_DEBUG` is not defined, then the macro `debug_printf` is replaced by nothing (or rather, an empty line).

Comment: care to give an example?

Comment: @suud Of course, because nothing does nothing (and is very portable!) while `__noop` seems vert compiler specific *and* you don't know if the compiler actually generates a `nop` assembler instruction for it.